# mod_rewrite rule gives 404 errors

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, web

I am **having problems** with mod_rewrite which is throwing me the same error 404 is as follows:

```
 RewriteRule ^music.mp3?id=(.*)$ music.php?id= [L]
```

i need url /music.mp3?id=1  and real url /music.php?id=1

any idea??

I think something is misunderstood in the path RewriteRule

Comment: You should escape the `.` in `.mp3`

Comment: I do not understand you explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't match against the query string (everything after the **?** in the URL) in a `RewriteRule`. But you're not really matching against it anyways, it looks like you just need to appended to your target URI, so:

```
RewriteRule ^music\.mp3$ music.php [L]
```

Should be good enough. Any query string parameters (like `?id=1`) will automatically get appended at the end.

Answer (score 0):

In your expression (the engine rule), what you want to say is:

"When the url starts with `music.mp3?id=`, take whatever is after the `=` and change the URL to `music.php?id=` and put the part after `id=`"

In regular expressions the `.` character has special meaning. If you want to say "the dot character", and not give it special meaning, you need to escape it, but putting a `\` behind it, like this:

`^music\.mp3?id=(.*)$`

@Jon Lin already gave you the other part, which is about query strings.